# Jackson serialization of generic java.time attribute does not work on Android API 21 (but does on 29)

Tags: java, android, jackson

I am using the new Android Studio 4.0 desugaring feature to use the `java.time` library back until API 21. Sadly, I have a weird error that I do not really understand. It occurs when serializing an object that has a property of type `LocalDate` (it's the same for `LocalDateTime`, and I assume it holds for all `java.time` classes).

As far as I understand the situation, I can serialize a single `LocalDate` object, I can serialize an object that has an attribute of type `LocalDate`, but I can not serialize an object that has the generic type of `LocalDate`.

This is my code for testing purposes:

```java
public static abstract class WhereTest<V> {
    public V v;
}

public static class T1 extends WhereTest<LocalDateTime> {
}

public static class T2 {
    public LocalDate l = LocalDate.now();
}
```

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(LocalDate.now());
System.out.println("--test-- json string: " + json);
json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new T2());
System.out.println("--test-- json string: " + json);
json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new T1());
System.out.println("--test-- json string: " + json);
```

On my API 29 emulator, this works fine and outputs something like:

```
--test-- json string: {"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"},"dayOfMonth":22,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":174,"era":"CE","month":"JUNE","monthValue":6,"year":2020,"leapYear":true}
--test-- json string: {"l":{"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"},"dayOfMonth":22,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":174,"era":"CE","month":"JUNE","monthValue":6,"year":2020,"leapYear":true}}
--test-- json string: {"v":null}
```

However, on my API 21 emulator, the following happens:

```
--test-- json string: {"month":"JUNE","year":2020,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"},"dayOfMonth":22,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":174,"era":"CE","monthValue":6,"leapYear":true}
--test-- json string: {"l":{"month":"JUNE","year":2020,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"},"dayOfMonth":22,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":174,"era":"CE","monthValue":6,"leapYear":true}}
Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ..., PID: 6125
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.../....MainActivity}: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type java.time.LocalDateTime not present
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type java.time.LocalDateTime not present
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:67)
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:76)
        at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70)
        at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55)
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:75)
        at libcore.reflect.Types.getType(Types.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:1161)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.getGenericSuperclass(ClassUtil.java:1204)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._resolveSuperClass(TypeFactory.java:1416)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1379)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1284)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(TypeFactory.java:698)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.constructType(MapperConfig.java:306)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:518)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:799)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:308)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:4374)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3629)
        at ....MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.time.LocalDateTime
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:65)
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:76) 
        at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70) 
        at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55) 
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:75) 
        at libcore.reflect.Types.getType(Types.java:56) 
        at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:1161) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.getGenericSuperclass(ClassUtil.java:1204) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._resolveSuperClass(TypeFactory.java:1416) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1379) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1284) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(TypeFactory.java:698) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.constructType(MapperConfig.java:306) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:518) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:799) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:308) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:4374) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3629) 
        at ....MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.time.LocalDateTime" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/...-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308) 
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:65) 
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:76) 
        at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70) 
        at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55) 
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:75) 
        at libcore.reflect.Types.getType(Types.java:56) 
        at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:1161) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.getGenericSuperclass(ClassUtil.java:1204) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._resolveSuperClass(TypeFactory.java:1416) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1379) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1284) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(TypeFactory.java:698) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.constructType(MapperConfig.java:306) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:518) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:799) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:308) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:4374) 
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3629) 
        at ....MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.time.LocalDateTime
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 35 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
```

The important parts in my app-level build.gradle are:

```
compileOptions {
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.5'
}
```

And in my project-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    }
}
```

Note (not sure if needed): In the `AndroidManifest`, the `application` has `android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`.